# Uploading issue in s3 bucket?

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I am using aws-sdk to upload a file. I use upload method instead of put. When I try to upload a file and see it's progress, it goes to 80% and then fails back to 10 or sometime at 0. I tried to upload different mp4 files but it's not working at all.

Comment: Some of my client able to upload it from India but the same process not working at all on california. Can you suggest what was the issue or I need to use multipart upload?

Comment: What language SDK? Do you have any output you can provide from the app?

Comment: Yes. I am using aws-sdk npm package for Angular2.

Comment: Oh! I got what is the problem. Actually when network is slow, aws-sdk request time out fire event to cancel the request and start with again.